# All MySQL databases appear to have disappeared

Tags: mysql, database

I'm running CentOS 6.7 with MySQL 5.1.73 and it appears as if all of the MySQL databases have disappeared within the past hour.

MySQL starts up without any issues, however when running `show databases;` as root, the only databases that are shown are information_schema and mysql. None of the other databases that were there earlier are present now. All of the MySQL users are still present though.

I've had a look in the MySQL data directory, and the files/directories that are there are ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, mysql, and mysql.sock. There doesn't seem to be any trace of the other databases that I had.

I'd like to know if it's possible to retrieve my data, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can restore from your backups.

Comment: I think what Michael Hampton is saying is - if the data matters - you should have a workflow where you have backups established before you start in on all this. for example whenever possible I create the backup BEFORE I do anything else by building scip

Comment: ... else by building SQL scripts - then restore those to the DB

Comment: A question we really should ask as these things rarely happen by themselves - What did you do ?

Answer (score 3):

With the information you have provided there isn't really much we can say. You have lost all of your databases. You will need to recover them from your backups or recreate them from original data.

---

If you look in your logs, you may find some information that will help you figure out what caused this problem. Which may lead to a different solution.